# Exception thrown in swift - Void is not convertible to FBSDKGraphRequestHandler?

Tags: swift, void

My code is:

```
let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", 
parameters: ["fields": "id, name, gender"])

graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({
    (connection, result, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        print(error)

    } else if let result = result {

        PFUser.currentUser()?["gender"] = result["gender"]
        PFUser.currentUser()?["name"] = result["name"]
      try  PFUser.currentUser()?.save()

    let userId = result["id"] as! String
```

I receive the following error:

> Void is not convertible to FBSDKGraphRequestHandler!

Why am I receiving such error?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm getting the exact same error. Trying to follow along with Rob Percival's Swift iOS tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

See if you can make the closure's parameters specific, like this:

```
request.startWithCompletionHandler({
        (connection:FBSDKGraphRequestConnection?, result:AnyObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

});
```

You should be able to leave the `-> Void` out.